# In python why does super behave this way with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python

So we have a code snippet below.  I don't understand why it behave this way. Why does `super(B, self).go()` resolves to the `go` method of the `C` class?

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("go B go!")

class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")

class D(B, C):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("go D go!")

d = D()
d.go()
# go A go!
# go C go!
# go B go!
# go D go!
```

Comment: Have you read the MRO document yet? https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ explains not just the what, but the *why*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite its name, `super` does not necessarily refer to a superclass. `super(B, self)` refers to the class in `self`'s MRO that follows `B`.

You can see the MRO for D with

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

This means that from `d.go`, `super(D, self)` refers to `B`. When `B.go` is called as a result, `super(B, self)` refers to `C`, *not* `A`. This is because `self` is still an instance of `D`, so it is `D.__mro__` that dictates what gets called next, not the static superclass of `B`.

The most important thing to remember about `super` is that inside `Foo.go`, you *do not know* what class `super(Foo, self)` will refer to, because you do not know if `self` is an instance of `Foo` or a descendent of `Foo`.

Comment: A useful thing to note: MRO stands for "method resolution order" - literally the order in which `super` methods are executed. Another way to think about this is "what would you expect to happen". It seems obvious that `A.go` should _not_ be called twice. So if it should be called only once, when _should_ it be called. The answer is the MRO order.